# What's causing memory leak in the following example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Clicking `add elements` button adds 1000 divs. And clicking `remove elements` removes 1000 elements. Also I am not attaching any event handler so I think I don't need to call `off()` on the divs before I call `remove()` on them.
[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/labeeb/pen/peBpdL?editors=1000)

```
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
<button id="addDivs">add elements</button>
<button id="removeDivs">remove elements</button>


<div id="box"></div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$("#addDivs").on("click", function(){

    var i;
    var div;

    for(i=0; i< 1000; i++){
        div = $("<div>");
        div.html(i);
        $("#box").append(div);

        //div.on("click",function(){
        //  console.log( $(this).text() );
        //});
    }   

});



$("#removeDivs").on("click", function(){

    $("#box div").each(function(){
        //$(this).off();
        $(this).remove();
    });


});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot of chrome timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCZ7w.png)
At the start and end of timeline I did garbage collected.

Comment: Please fix your codepen link, it has to be copy-pasted currently. Thanks

Comment: @AnuradhaKulkarni Have fixed, works now.

Comment: Don't append elements inside a loop. Push all the elements to an array and do ONE `.append()` call after the loop. That will already save you tons of time and memory. AS programmed, the browser has to access the page at least 2000 times to append all the divs, where 2 times would suffice. Same goes for the removal. If the box contains nothing but divs, just setting the innerHTML of the box to nothing will remove ALL the divs in one go, instead of removing them one by one, each time triggering a DOM lookup. Techncially there is no memory leak, just very inefficient usage of memory.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if you have 1000 divs or just 1 div. The increase is because of your event handler of buttons not divs. Try adding this code to event handler of remove button:

```
$("#removeDivs").off("click");
$("#addDivs").off("click");
```

You will notice the usage drops down immediately.